# How to split a string by an empty string delimiter

Tags: c#, split

In java,

```
String.split("");
```

is possible.
ex)

```
String[] str = "Hello world!".split("")
```

Like this, I want to split String without escape sequence. 
But in C#, I tried it and IDE said 'Error'. Is there any solution?

edit)
Code:

```
String[] str = "Hello world!".split("");
```

the result is `str[0] = H`, `str[1] = e`, ...(in java)

In C#, I tried

```
strI[i] = "Hello World!".Split('');
```

And the result is

> 'error CS1011: Empty character literal
>   I want to split string with Empty literal.

Comment: Hi @Yeongsoo, could you please post the code you tried that gives you the error?

Comment: What you expected from this? `"Hello world!".split("")` and what was wrong?

Comment: `I want to split String without escape sequence` what does this exactly mean

Comment: You want every char? ToCharArray().

Comment: From [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20char%29). `public static String[] split(String str)` _Splits the provided text into an array, using whitespace as the separator. Whitespace is defined by Character.isWhitespace(char)._

Comment: It's the same in C# [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2), We assume that default split char is space. `var result = "MyString".Split();` or `var input = "MyString here"; var result = input.Split();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that no overloaded methods of `String.Split()` accepts a string as first argument like what you used. Following are the possible [overloaded methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

[image]

The thing you are looking for is to split a string into characters. For that you can depend on [`String.ToCharArray Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904309(v=vs.71).aspx), which will Copies the characters in this instance to a Unicode character array.:

```
char[] charArray = "Hello world!".ToCharArray();
```

So that we can access each characters using its index, that means -  `charArray[0]` will be `H`.

If you need the splitted characters into a string array means you can use something like this:

```
string[] strArray = "Hello world!".Select(x=> x.ToString())
                                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: If you only want to _read_ the chars by index you don't need ToCharArray. `"hello"[1] == 'e'` is true.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error is because there is no method with the signature matching your call. In other words, when you call Split method, you must pass the first parameter as a character array or string array, whereas you are passing the first argument as simply a string.

Following call would not throw any error since it matches the signature of Split method.

```
string[] sArray = s.Split(new string[] {""}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

However, above method will result in nothing productive since the resulting array will contain only one element whose value will be original string.

If your goal was to split a string into individual characters then you can use code like below.

```
string s = "some string";
var splitString = s.ToCharArray();
```